How to switch MSI BIOS from UEFI mode to LEGACY+UEFI mode?
Question, said differently:
How to set MSI BIOS to Legacy?
How to activate the LEGACY+UEFI option?
How to switch and hold (maintain) the change to LEGACY+UEFI ?
Linux commands:
sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer
Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
(MSI motherboard)
Latest BIOS version installed:
sudo dmidecode -s bios-Release-Date
08/20/2024
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.J0
sudo dmidecode --type bios |grep -i 'legacy' 
USB legacy is supported
sudo dmidecode --type bios |grep -i 'boot' 
Boot from CD is supported
Selectable boot is supported
BIOS boot specification is supported
.
12th Generation Processor
lscpu | grep "Model name" 
Model name: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12500
12th Generation Processor
cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed -En 's/^.*name\s+:.*-(1[0-9]|[0-9])[0-9]+.*$/Intel Gen: \1/p;T;q'
Intel Gen: 12
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657105/how-to-check-processor-generation
.
definitions:
CSM = Compatibility Support Module
UEFI = Unified Extensible Firmware Interface
Made 3 BIOS changes for booting
from UEFI
to CSM Legacy
Note:  Order of changes 1. 2. 3. below might be important.
boot to MSI BIOS with F11 ...

SETTINGS (Left side of screen) \
Advanced \
BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode was = UEFI
BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode now = CSM
thus change from UEFI to CSM

SECURITY (Right side of screen, Right bottom corner) \
Secure Boot \
Secure Boot = Disabled

SETTINGS (Left side of screen) \
Boot \
Boot mode select = LEGACY+UEFI


.
After above 3 changes are done then
MSI BIOS
Save Changes and Reboot.
or
F10 = Save configuration and exit?
.
Note: The above manually selected BIOS saved values are cancelled.
Because:
While booting, BIOS values are changed by BIOS.
While booting, screen message, 3 seconds:
There is no VBIOS support detected in this card.
'BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode' settings in BIOS will be changed to 'UEFI'.
Press any key or wait 3 seconds to continue.
see image below:

.
background:
computer1, 03rd Generation Processor, SpinRite 6.1 boots fine.
computer2, 12th Generation Processor, SpinRite 6.1 not booting.
Thus the USB stick (disk) is fine and
SpinRite 6.1 runs fine on computer1, 3rd Generation Processor.
SpinRite 6.1 uses FreeDOS.
using:
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:' 
3.3
dmidecode --version
.
How to switch MSI BIOS from UEFI mode to LEGACY+UEFI mode?
--

Frame challenge: WHY do you want to do that in 2024?

Change it within the Settings. Have you replaced the CMOS battery?

Question:  WHY do you want to do that in 2024?
Answer:  in 2024 there is a need to Boot to Legacy to
run 2024 software, new version just released months ago,
SpinRite version 6.1, see SR61 details above.
SpinRite version 6.0 is decades old, but,
SpinRite version 6.1 is new in 2024, now just months old.

there are lots of recovery software out there running in Linux and Windows, why SpinRite?

And in any case the answer was given by Ramhoubd already: Change it within UEFI settings, that should be all, IF SUPPORTED. Most hardware coming out now no longer support Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode. If that's your you simply can't, end of story.

Change it within UEFI settings, 3 values were
changed, 2 of 3 values were under SETTINGS button,
see above.  Changing values manually was undone
automatically by MSI Bios on Restart or Reboot, see
above.  The Bios changes were reset by Bios see
above wording and see image (foto):
_ There is no VBIOS support detected in this card.
'BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode' settings in BIOS will be
changed to 'UEFI'. _

@joseph22 - Did you replace the CMOS battery? I am confused by your question, you have a hardware issue, causing your inability to set the firmware option you want to change. Spinrite is absolutely not helpful in a case like this. Why are we talking about it?

Did you replace the CMOS battery?  No.
Because computer runs fine and clock is accurate.
Clock is similar to atomic clock time.
Bios settings are being changed by Bios on Boot.
The Bios or set the firmware option is done
but on Boot the Bios changes settings back, see above
foto (photograph).  Thus posted Question.

Why are we talking about it?
(SR61 = SpinRite version 6.1)
Because SR61 needs Legacy Bios to run.
Changes made to Bios are accepted by Bios but on
boot are changed by Bios, see evidence of change
in foto (photograph) image.

there are lots of recovery software out there running in
Linux and Windows, why SpinRite? –
SpinRite is a side issue, not the main question.
why SR = SpinRite? Because SR was purchased decades
ago and in 2024 SR email arrived stating free update
from SR60 to SR61.

During those decades many HDD
(Hard Disk Drives) became useless.  Time was spent
to make useless HDD useful.  Nothing worked.
Thus HDD was slotted for destruction.  But with
SR61 these HDDs are now working fine.
Re-purpose HDDs for new experiments.
Once useless HDDs are now useful HDD thanks to
SR61 Level 2 and
SR61 Level 4.
back to main Question:
SR61 runs on Gen3 computer.
SR61 not running on Gen 12 computer, due to
automatic Bios changes on boot.  Thus posted Question.

@joseph22 - Have you replaced the CMOS battery? You really should answer me question. Your CMOS battery needing to be replaced would explain the firmware is rolling back your changes.

Because computer runs fine and clock is accurate doesn't mean the battery is fine. Computers don't need that battery to run, ONLY to keep the firmware settings and the clock is set each time it connects to the internet. You REALLY need to pay attention that what is being suggested.

CMOS battery at 3.16 Volts DC on Saturday-2-November-2024

Yeah... Replace it.


The above manually selected BIOS saved values are cancelled.
Because:

While booting, BIOS values are changed by BIOS.


Based on this description it appears you need to replace your CMOS battery on the motherboard.

There is way to boot to Spinrite 6.1 without booting to Legacy mode

Boot Issue with Intel® Arc™ A750 or A770 Graphics Cards on the Intel site says the following error reported in the question:

"There is no VBIOS support detected in this card. The 'BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode' setting in BIOS will be changed to 'UEFI'. Press any key or wait 3 seconds to continue."

Can occur with the environment:

Systems with an Intel® Arc™ A770 or A750 Graphics Card with VBIOS 20.0.1049. Seen on MSI PRO Z690-A WiFi DDR4 and Z790 Motherboards.

The solution given on the Intel site is to update the Arc Graphics card firmware:

Starting on driver 31.0.101.4644, the installer package contains a firmware updater for Arc Graphics Cards, including fixes and improvements for some known issues. Please install this or a newer driver to get your Arc Graphics card firmware updated.

While this is speculative answer about the possible cause since the specific motherboard, graphics card and firmware are not specified in the question, it is an alternative explanation for the issue compared to the other answer which says the CMOS battery is a possible cause.

Also found There is No VBIOS on this card on the MSI forum which reported the same error appeared randomly:

So my issue is I'm getting this error There is no VBIOS support detected in this card. BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode setting in BIOS will be changed to 'Enabled' randomly but only when i restart the pc through windows if i cold start the pc no issues whatsoever.

There is no real conclusion to the cause of the error in the above MSI forum thread. Initially the problem went away when the PCIe power cable to the graphics card was changed, but when the original cable was fitted the error couldn't be repeated.


There is no VBIOS support detected in this card.
'BIOS CSM/UEFI Mode' settings in BIOS will be changed to 'UEFI'.

This message means: your GPU does not support legacy BIOS boot mode, only native UEFI mode. Because of this, the MSI BIOS "helpfully" switches the boot mode to UEFI only.
With your current GPU, booting in legacy BIOS mode would cause the GPU to be disabled (= black screen/headless mode) until a modern OS was booted up and its GPU drivers were loaded. The legacy BIOS boot process would be unable to display any boot messages, which would make debugging any boot issues rather difficult. FreeDOS, like MS-DOS, relies on VBIOS for display.
If there is a GPU firmware upgrade for your GPU that includes legacy VBIOS functionality, installing that would make it possible to display things in legacy mode, and so the MSI BIOS should allow the LEGACY+UEFI boot mode to be selected then.
If no such GPU firmware upgrade is available, then you might have to replace (downgrade?) your GPU with one that includes the legacy VBIOS functionality.
